# ngChange a bunch of dropdowns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select

So I need to entirely change a group of drop downs that appear based on the selection of one dropdown. I believe ngChange is the way to go about it, but I am not entirely sure how to change between two sets of divs (or if that is even the best way of doing it.

So I have this dropdown:

```
                <div class="input-group" theme="bootstrap" style="">
                <label>Product Type</label>
                <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control"  style="" ng-model="event.etype" ng-change="setOptions()" id="etype">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Product</option>
                    <option ng-click="type = 'x'">X</option>
                    <option ng-click="type = 'y'">Y</option>
                    <option ng-click="type = 'z'">Z</option>
                    <option ng-click="type = 'q'">Q</option>
                    <option ng-click="type = 'w'">W</option>
                </select>
                </div>
```

If the choice is X, I need one set of drop downs (contained in one row), and if it is anything else, I need an entirely different set (contained in another row).

Here are how the drop downs look:

```
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <label>Numbers</label>
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Numbers">{{$item.admin_user.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="a in ams"> {{a.admin_user.name}} </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
          </div>
            </div>


        <div class="row col-lg-12" id="nonX">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group" theme="bootstrap">
                  <label>Super Heroes</label>
                  <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control" ng-model="superhero"  id="script">
                      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Superhero</option>
                      <option ng-repeat="superhero in superheroes" ng-value={{superhero}} ng-click="selectHeroe(superhero)">{{superhero.name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row col-lg-12" id="noniPad"> 


            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group" theme="bootstrap">
                  <label>Screen</label>
                  <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control" ng-model="event.screen" id="screen">
                      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Screen</option>
                      <option ng-repeat="screen in screens" ng-value={{screen}} ng-click="selectScreen(screen)">{{screen.name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="input-group" theme="bootstrap">
                <label>Misc Asset</label>
                <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control"  ng-model="event.miscasset" id="miscasset">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Misc Asset</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="miscasset in miscassets" ng-value={{miscasset}} ng-click="slectMiscAsset(miscasset)">{{miscasset.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>


                <div class="row m-b-sm m-t-sm"></div>
    </div>
```

The separate drop downs both appear in different rows. So I would need one row to appear if they select iPad and one row to appear if they do not select an iPad.

I would love some help. Thank you!

Comment: I found this maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510713/angularjs-dependent-dropdown-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to set the dropdowns of each one depending on the parent selection. There's no need to create a duplicate div to hold both sets of dropdows.

*I removed all css classes and any other markup not relevant to the ng-change to make it clearer.*

Your parent dropdown would look like this:

```
<div>
   <label>Product Type</label>
   <select ng-model="event.etype" ng-change="setOptions(event.etype)">
      <option value="">Select a Product</option>
      <option ng-repeat="etype in etypes" ng-value="etype" ng-bind="etype"></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Take special notice of how the `setOptions` handler is being passed the ng-model value. This means when an option is selected, it'll automatically set ng-model="event.etype" to the value of that option.

To support this behavior in your controller you need to provide the array of event types:

```
$scope.etypes = ['gif', 'photo', 'ipad', 'video', 'print'];
```

Then, on your `setOptions` method you'll get the selected option and filter your descendant dropdowns

```
var options1 = [{
    etype: 'ipad',
    value: '1'
}, {
    etype: 'gif',
    value: '2'
}];

$scope.setOptions = function (etype) {
    $scope.scripts = options1.filter(function (item) {
        return item.etype == etype;
    });
};
```

What this means is that `setOptions` will set the descendant dropdowns based on the etype value passed in. In this example I'm limiting to $scope.scripts only but you can set as many as needeed. As you can see options1 is just an array which contains the etype property which I need to filter against.

Finally on your descendant dropdowns you would use the filtered options:

```
<select ng-model="event.script">
   <option value="" selected disabled>Select Script</option>
   <option ng-repeat="script in scripts" ng-value="script.value" ng-bind="script.value"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks @radyz. This makes a little sense to me, but I am confused about how this will filter based on a particular etype? Basically there are two sets of drop downs: one for iPad and one for everything else. 

I don't understand the setOptions part of it and how this will filter based on one etype and show that dropdown or not. Thank you again for your help! I'm sorry I'm a newb

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it a little bit clearer. Hope it helps

Comment: Alright, I think that I am just entirely misunderstanding. Lets imagine it as rows. So I have two separate rows that contain whatever. Lets ignore the fact that they are drop downs. I need one row to appear if an iPad is selected and one row to appear if something other than an iPad is selected. That is what I'm struggling to do. As far as I understand, I would have to explicate a bunch of different options in "options1" when there are only two relevant options. iPad and not iPad. I'm sorry, I am not very familiar with angular!

Comment: I updated my original post. It now clearly shows no overlap between the drop downs they can choose from.

Comment: If you have different arrays for each you can just `if (etype === 'iPad') { $scope.scripts = row1; } else { $scope.scripts = row2; }` inside the `setOptions` method.

Comment: I used ```ng-hide="event.etype == null || event.etype=='ipad'"``` and ```ng-show="event.etype == 'ipad'"```. These seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-hide="event.etype == null || event.etype=='ipad'"` and `ng-show="event.etype == 'ipad'"` on the row tags solved my issue!